# How to connect to remote mongoDB via ssh (via Sacred)? connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, mongodb, ssh-tunnel

I have two computers: Ubuntu1 and Ubuntu2. 
Ubuntu1 runs MongoDB with database Sacred3. 
I want to run connect from U2 to U1 via ssh and store there my experiment results.

What I tried and failed:
1. I installed mongo DB, created sacred3, I have ssh key to it. 
I edited `/etc/mongod.conf` adding:

`# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0`

Then I enabled port forwarding with

`ssh -fN  -i ~/.ssh/sacred_key-pair.pem -L 6666:localhost:27017 ubuntu@106.969.696.969` // (with proper ip)

so, as I undertstand, if I connect to my localhost:6666 it will be forwarded to 106.969.696.969:27017

So after that, I'm runnig an experiment with [Sacred framework](https://sacred.readthedocs.io/en/stable/observers.html):

python exp1.py -m localhost:6666:sacred3

and this should write experiment to remote DB, HOWEVER i I get:

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

which is driving me mad. please help!

Comment: your ssh tunnel (`X:host:Y`) command suggests that your `localhot:6666` is forwarded to `localhost:27017`, and not `106.969.whatever:27017`. If you want do set that up, you should have something like `-L localhost:6666:106.969.696.969:27017`. mongo is not listening on the loopback.

Answer (score 1):

Your error says pymongo is looking for mongod on `localhost:27017`

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017`

But it isn't there, you've forwarded it to `localhost:6666`. The connection string in your code must have a hardcoded default you'll need to edit.

Or, if nothing is running on localhost:27017 you can tunnel directly:

`ssh -fN  -i ~/.ssh/sacred_key-pair.pem -L 27017:localhost:27017 ubuntu@106.969.696.969`

Other useful commands are

- List ssh processes

`ps aux | grep ssh`

- Which process is using a port (27107 in this case)

`sudo netstat -lnpt | awk '$4 ~ /:27107/ {sub(/\/.*/, "", $7); print $7}'`

- Free up a port by killing the process using it

`kill <pid>`

Also bind to local host, using 0.0.0.0 is making mongodb available to anyone anywhere that can reach the server.

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```